# Change the background color of a div after some interval

Tags: javascript, html, colors

Hey i am trying to change the background color of a div. I have written a script to change the background color of the body. The code is below

```
<script>
colors = new Array('black', 'red', 'green');
function annoyingEffect(tic){
tic %= colors.length;
document.bgColor = colors[tic];
setTimeout("annoyingEffect("+(tic+1)+")", 2000);}
</script>
<body onload="annoyingEffect(0)">

</body>
```

But if i try to add a div and insert the onload="annoyingEffect(0)" function inside it, it doesn't work. What I'm i missing?

Comment: seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FH7Zx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/NSJDR/5/) (http://jsfiddle.net/NSJDR/5/) how you change the body and a `<div>`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            colors = new Array('blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown', 'orange');

            function annoyingEffect(tic){
                tic %= colors.length;
                document.bgColor = colors[tic];
                setTimeout("annoyingEffect("+(tic+1)+")", 1000);
            }

            function annoyingEffectOnDiv(tic, divId){
                tic %= colors.length;
                divVar = document.getElementById(divId);
                divVar.style.background = colors[tic];
                setTimeout("annoyingEffectOnDiv("+(tic+1)+", '"+divId+"')", 1000);
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="annoyingEffect(0); annoyingEffectOnDiv(2, 'divtest');">
        <div id="divtest">
            <label>HELLOOOOOA :D</label>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: thanx mate that did the trick but i had to change the code a bit to suit my need but it worked perfect :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this line

```
setTimeout("annoyingEffect("+(tic+1)+")", 2000);
```

should be

```
setTimeout(function(){ annoyingEffect(tic+1); }, 2000);
```

function parameters aren't passed as strings

Comment: You have to pass the function as a string in setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/Fr6tW/

Add in your JS:

```
document.getElementById('customid').style.background = colors[tic]; \*your div id*\
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="annoyingEffect(0)">
    <div id="customid"></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
colors = new Array('black', 'red', 'green');
function annoyingEffect(tic){
    tic %= colors.length;
    //document.bgColor = colors[tic];
    document.getElementById('customid').style.background = colors[tic];   
    setTimeout("annoyingEffect("+(tic+1)+")", 2000);}
```