# Dynamically Change Color with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a Jquery script written to change the color of an object over time from (0, 0, 0) to (255, 255, 0).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var r = 0;
    var g = 0;
    changeColor(r, g);
});

function changeColor(r, g){
    var newColor = "(" + r + "," + g + ", 0)";

    $("p").css({"color": newColor});
    $("#diag").html(newColor);

    r+=1;
    g+=1;

    if(r <= 255 && g <= 255){
        window.setTimeout(function(){changeColor(r, g);}, 20);
    }
}
```

The HTML is:

```
    <p>Hello</p>
    <div id="diag"></div>
```

However, although the function does execute (evident through how the newColor is repeatedly displayed in #diag), the actual color of the p element does not change. Are there any ideas as to why this may be? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `$.each`

Comment: Wats the problem with http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qfulj  ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207356/change-the-background-color-of-a-div-after-some-interval?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change this line `var newColor = "(" + r + "," + g + ", 0)";`

to this

```
var newColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + ", 0)";
```